# What is the search path for importing .m files?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a project where I am importing source files into a separate source file.

```
// In my .m
#import "UIDevice+HardwareString.m"
#import "NSObject+QueryComponents.m"
```

I'm getting a "file not found" warning. The file is in my project and a member of the target. I'm importing the associated ".h" files elsewhere -- they are in the same folder and are found.

I really do want to import the .m files -- I'm importing them to prevent the code from being optimized else while building a static library.

How are the .m file searched for?

Comment: Hmm. It seems if I put the directory explicitly into my Header search path, it finds these files. Odd that it did not complain about the .h files.